# Tesseract Small Text accuracy and Google Translate OCR for Android

Tags: android, tesseract, training-data

i just want to ask some question..

we know that Google translate has an OCR feature and for me it's almost 99% accurate even for small texts.
i wonder what technology did they use and can it be implemented on Android?

i am using Tesseract and i got nothing when i take small text. or maybe there is a tutorial to increase the accuracy for small texts?

people said to have my text be changed into minimum 300dpi, i tried to search tutorial about it and i haven't found it yet.

Comment: @dcharms if you have time please kindly check this question